# Uninitialized constant (Name Error) in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, configuration, environment-variables

I have this mynewapp_environment.rb file in /config/initializers in my new rails app.

`MyNewApp=AppConfig.new
require './config/mynewapp/default.rb'`

When I start the rails server, I get the following errors.

```
/home/dev/mynewapp/config/initializers/mynewapp_environment.rb:1:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant AppConfig (NameError)
    from /home/dev/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rails-dev-boost-0.3.0/lib/rails_development_boost/loadable_patch.rb:13:in `load'
    from /home/dev/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/engine.rb:652:in `block in load_config_initializer'
    from /home/dev/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `instrument'
```

My app_config.rb is present in /lib folder.

I have made sure that the app name is consistent in every file in the app folder. Any leads as to how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Where is your AppConfig defined? Should not be some Application class name?

Another place you can try it to put these code into RAILS_ROOT/config/preinitializer.rb, this file is loaded *before* any of the framework components.

Comment: The file is present in /lib folder.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out!
I didn't update my `application.rb` for autoloading the /lib directory. Writing `config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)` in `application.rb` fixed the issue.